# C++ and Openmp with critical too slow

Tags: openmp, rcpp

I tried use Rcpp and Openmp to accelerate my code. Here is my cpp code. I wonder why. What is the best way to accelerate this code by openmp.

```
 // #include <Rcpp.h>
 #include <vector>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <RcppArmadillo.h>
 #include "omp.h"

 using namespace Rcpp;
 using namespace std;

 // Function subset("[.data.frame");
 // [[Rcpp::plugins(openmp) ]]
 // [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]] 
 // [[Rcpp::export]]
 DataFrame reformdata(DataFrame rawfile, DataFrame genefile){
     vector<string> rawchr = rawfile["chr"];
     NumericVector rawpos = rawfile["start"];
     vector<string> genechr = genefile["X.1"];
     NumericVector genestart = genefile["TSS.start"];
     NumericVector geneend = genefile["TSS.end"];

     vector<string> geneID = genefile["X"];
     NumericVector rawnumCs = rawfile["numCs"];
     NumericVector rawnumTs = rawfile["numTs"];
     NumericVector rawmethyl = rawfile["methyl"];


     int n_raw = rawchr.size();
     int n_gene = genechr.size();
     int i = 0,j = 0;
     vector<string> outputgeneID;
     vector<string> outputchr;
     NumericVector outputstart;
     NumericVector outputend;
     NumericVector outputmethyl;
     NumericVector outputnumCs;
     NumericVector outputnumTs;

     #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(8)
     for(i = 0; i < n_gene; i++){
         string loc_gene_name = genechr[i];
         int gene_start = genestart[i];
         int gene_end = geneend[i];

         for(j = 0;j < n_raw; j++){
             string raw_name = rawchr[j];
             int raw_pos = rawpos[j];
             if(raw_name.compare(loc_gene_name)==0&&raw_pos >= gene_start&&raw_pos <= gene_end){

                 #pragma omp critical
                 {
                     outputgeneID.push_back(geneID[i]);
                     outputchr.push_back(rawchr[j]);
                     outputstart.push_back(rawpos[j]);
                     outputend.push_back(rawpos[j]);
                     outputmethyl.push_back(rawmethyl[j]);
                     outputnumCs.push_back(rawnumCs[j]);
                     outputnumTs.push_back(rawnumTs[j]);
                 }
             }
        }
   }
   return   DataFrame::create(Named("geneID")=outputgeneID,Named("chr")=outputchr,
                       Named("start")=outputstart,Named("end")=outputend,
                        Named("methyl")=outputmethyl,
                         Named("numCs")=outputnumCs,Named("numTs")=outputnumTs);

}
```

I just want to input two Dataframe in R, and then do a match between this two data frame. Maybe the push_back is the problem where it is. Is there a easy way to avoid it? I am dealing with big data, speed is important.

Comment: Please provide sample inputs with your question.

Comment: In addition, note that you should not be using `.push_back` on any `Rcpp` object as this forces deep copies. Best to switch over to `std::vector<T>` or use `arma::vec`.

Comment: You may want to consider the codereview stackexchange site.

Comment: The trouble is that almost the entire 'payload' of the parallel region is enclosed in a `critical` section.  Off the top of my head I'd throw the entire code away and start again with data structures that are more easily shared.